# Can anyone find the error in this code, the output file is not showing the contents

Tags: arrays, c, matrix-multiplication

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int r1, r2, c1, c2;
printf("Enter number of rows and colums for mat1-");        //matrix1//
scanf("%d %d", &r1, &c1);
int m1[r1][c1];
for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c1; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter mat1[%d][%d]-", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &m1[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("Enter no of rows columns for mat2-");          //matrix2//
scanf("%d %d", &r2, &c2);
int m2[r2][c2];
for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter mat2[%d][%d]-", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &m2[i][j]);
    }
}
int m3[r1][c2];
for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)    //matrix multiplication//
{
    for (int j = 0; i < c2; j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < r1; k++)
        {
            sum += (m1[i][k] * m2[k][j]);
        }
        m3[i][j] = sum;
    }
    FILE *outputFile = fopen("output.txt", 'w');
    if (outputFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)    /*this part is not working*/
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++)
        {
            fprintf(outputFile, "%d", m3[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(outputFile, "\n");
    }
    fclose(outputFile);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow.
The original question was- Write a program to perform matrix multiplication. The size of matrix and the elements of the matrices are obtained from the user through console input. write the resultant matrix to the file "output.txt".

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < c2; j++)` is a likely candidate... `i` and `j` look too much alike to be used as loop counters together. Try using longer names like "outer" and "inner"...

Comment: Additionally, why is the 2nd last closing brace **after** the `return 0;`? And why is the `fopen()` **inside** the last outer loop? Perhaps you need to look at the code both _up close_ AND from a _bird's eye_ perspective...

Comment: Additionally, the innermost loop of multiplication should be `for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++)`,
not `for (int k = 0; k < r1; k++)`.

Comment: Please note that in `fopen("output.txt", 'w')` the `'w'` is an error, you should pass `"w"`. If the compiler haven't warned you, enable more warnings.

Comment: I agree with the diagnoses, but I’m not convinced by the inner/outer recommendation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < c2; j++)` this loop will either never be entered or an endless loop, depending on the result of `i < c2` Furthermore your have a `for (int i ...` loop inside a `for (int i...` which is allowed, but may be very confusing and makes it impossible to use the "outer" `i` within the inner loop's body

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have a typo in the second `for` loop of the matrix multiplication. You wrote `for (int j = 0; i < c2; j++)` instead of `for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++)`. This causes an infinite loop and prevents the program from writing the result to the file. To fix this, you need to change `i` to `j` in the loop condition.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  int r1, r2, c1, c2;
  printf ("Enter number of rows and colums for mat1-"); //matrix1//[^2^][2]
  scanf ("%d %d", &r1, &c1);
  int m1 [r1] [c1];
  for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
      printf ("Enter mat1 [%d] [%d]-", i + 1, j + 1);
      scanf ("%d", &m1 [i] [j]);
    }
  }
  printf ("Enter no of rows columns for mat2-"); //matrix2//
  scanf ("%d %d", &r2, &c2);
  int m2 [r2] [c2];
  for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
      printf ("Enter mat2 [%d] [%d]-", i + 1, j + 1);
      scanf ("%d", &m2 [i] [j]);
    }
  }
  int m3 [r1] [c2];
  for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) //matrix multiplication//
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) //changed i to j here//
    {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < r1; k++) {
        sum += (m1 [i] [k] * m2 [k] [j]);
      }
      m3 [i] [j] = sum;
    }
  }
  FILE *outputFile = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
  if (outputFile == NULL) {
    printf ("Error");
    return 1;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) /*this part is now working*/
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
      fprintf (outputFile, "%d", m3 [i] [j]);
    }
    fprintf (outputFile, "\n");
  }
  fclose (outputFile);
  return 0;
}
```